# Where can I change the formatter settings in Sublime TypeScript plugin?

Tags: typescript, format, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin, formatter

In [the Sublime Text TypeScript plugin](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Sublime-Plugin), it is possible to automatically format your code. However, I would like to use a slightly different style (specifically, no spaces around { objects }). Is it possible to configure this somewhere? Couldn't find this anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit `editor_client.py` for now.

## More

Support is being tracked here : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Sublime-Plugin/issues/321#issuecomment-127380975